# Displaying widgets in the correct order when using callbacks in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I’ve made a very simple app in Streamlit (1.3.1) that:

1. Uses the file uploader widget to read in an Excel file
2. Gets the user to choose a worksheet they’re interested in previewing using a selectbox dropdown
3. Displays a preview of the worksheet

I’m using a callback from `st.selectbox` to display the preview, so that it only displays after the user has actively chosen a worksheet they’re interested in. But in order to do so I need to have defined my callback function before calling `st.selectbox` - and that’s leading the preview to appear above the file uploader and selectbox widgets in the app, rather than where I want it, below those widgets.

This is my code and a screengrab of my output.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# CREATE APP
# Add file_uploader
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(
    label='Upload a file', type=['xls', 'xlsx', 'xlsm'],
    key='file-uploader',
    help='''
        Upload an Excel file. The file must be
        closed in order for you to upload it.
    '''
)


# Define function that loads sheet preview
def load_sheet_preview():
    st.dataframe(df[st.session_state.selectbox_sheet])


# Add selectbox
if uploaded_file is not None:
    df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file, sheet_name=None)      # sheet_name=None needs explicitly including - it isn't the default        # noqa: E501

    st.selectbox(
        key='selectbox_sheet',
        label='Select worksheet',
        options=df.keys(),
        on_change=load_sheet_preview
    )
```

[image: Streamlit screngrab]

Wrapping the code that produces the file uploader and the selectbox in functions, in the order I want them to appear in the app, also doesn't sort the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve come up with a solution to this which involves (explicitly) using `st.session_state` rather than a callback and adding a default value to the dropdown options. The preview isn’t loaded while the default option is selected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io

import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

# CREATE APP
# Add file_uploader
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(
    label='Upload a file', type=['xls', 'xlsx', 'xlsm'],
    key='file-uploader',
    help='''
        Upload an Excel file. The file must be
        closed in order for you to upload it.
    '''
)

# Add selectbox
if 'selectbox_sheet' not in st.session_state:       # Initialise variable
    st.session_state['selectbox_sheet'] = '--'

if uploaded_file is not None:
    sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file, sheet_name=None)      # This creates a dictionary of dataframes. sheet_name=None needs explicitly including - it isn't the default        # noqa: E501

    default_option = {'--': ''}

    selectbox_options = dict(**default_option, **sheets_dict)     # Join dictionaries        # noqa: E501

    st.selectbox(
        key='selectbox_sheet',
        label='Select worksheet',
        options=selectbox_options.keys()
    )

# Load sheet preview
if st.session_state.selectbox_sheet != '--':
    st.dataframe(sheets_dict[st.session_state.selectbox_sheet])
```